# Infinite loop BUG in C

Tags: c, loops, debugging

This is a function in a calculator program. If the user type in a non digit, the loop operand 1 "must be an integer" will go infinite.

I know the do while loop is having issues but I don't know how to fix it. 
HELP????

```
int getop(int opno)
{
int val;        /* value read */
int rv;         /* value returned from scanf */
int *rv1 = &rv;
/*
 * loop until you get an integer or EOF
 */
do {
    /* prompt and read a value */
    printf("\toperand %d: ", opno);
    rv = scanf("%d", &val);
    /* oops ... bogus value */
    if (rv == 0)
        printf("\toperand must be an integer\n");
    /* loop until a valid value */
} while (*rv1 == 0);
/*
 * if it's EOF, say so and quit
 */
if (rv == EOF)
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

/*
 * otherwise, say what you read
 */
return(val);
}


int main(void)
{
int ch;         /* input character */
int op;         /* operation, derived from ch */
int op1, op2;       /* operands */
int result;     /* result to be printed */


/*
 * prompt the user for an operation
 */
printf("operation (+,-,*,/,%%)> ");

/*
 * loop until user says to quit
 */
while((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
    /* convert the character read to an operator */
    if ((op = valop(ch)) == ERROR){
        /* eat the rest of the line */
        while(ch != '\n' && (ch = getchar()) != EOF)
            ;
        printf("operation (+,-,*,/,%%)> ");
        continue;
    }
    /* get the operands */
    op1 = getop(1);
    op2 = getop(2);
    /*
     * if division operation by 0, complain
     * otherwise do the operation
     */
    if (isdivop(op) && op2 == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't have a denominator of 0\n");
    else{
        result = apply(op1, op, op2);
        printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", op1, ch, op2, result);
    }
    /* eat the rest of the line */
    while(ch != '\n' && (ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        ;
    /* prompt again */
    printf("operation (+,-,*,/,%%)> ");
   }
  putchar('\n');

 return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

Comment: `while (*rv1 == 0);` --> `while (rv != 1);`

Comment: When you get a bogus value it is still in the buffer. You need to read it

Comment: Debugger................................ DCV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If non-numeric data is entered, nothing matches the `%d` format specifier, and the input is left in the buffer.  So every time through the loop, it keeps trying to read the same invalid data, resulting in an infinite loop.

In the `(rv==0)` case, you need to flush the buffer by calling `getchar()` in a loop until you get a newline:

```
if (rv == 0) {
    printf("\toperand must be an integer\n");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
```